# Why are miniconda envs located in /path/to/miniconda/base/envs/ ? [homebrew install]

Tags: python, conda, homebrew, miniconda

I installed miniconda via homebrew ([cask](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/miniconda))

```
brew install miniconda
```

And created a new environment `myenv`

```
conda create -n myenv
```

I noticed that the path for this environment is at

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/myenv
```

instead of

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/myenv
```

Curious why it is organized this way, as I feel this is messing with my ability to use this environment with R reticulate.

Comment: Why would an intermediate `envs` folder mess with anything?

Comment: I don't know, but it seems it cannot see anything but the base env.

Comment: Maybe edit the question with how you are using "R reticulate"? You may need to activate an environment first before using it. Specifically, [`use_condaenv`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/use_python.html)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to mix the two. I'm just genuinely curious as to why the envs are organized in this manner in this miniconda. Doesn't seem to be the case in non-homebew miniconda installs. I got reticulate to work (use_conda env was not working properly; documented this here https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1327).

Comment: You'd have to ask the maintainers of the cask [why they wrote it that way](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/miniconda.rb#L26-L30). Homebrew itself has no control over the inner folders of a specific Cask

Answer (score 1):

According to [this PR that added the `base` directory](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/66544), they wanted a "stable" install path.